# Problem while using QtreeView to display and modify data from an oracle database

Tags: python, database, qt, qtreeview, pyside6

I am trying to use a `Qtreeview` to display items from a database. I currently can do this but I've got a problem when I want to modify the data stored in the `database` from the `Qtreeview`. I'd like to have an easy access between my database and the Qtreeview thanks to the primary key of my items.

As you can see in the code bellow, I tried to hide the name of the first columns with the `SetColumnHidden` method. Unfortunately, I can not access the data when it's hidden.

Is there any way to get this link between the data stored and the Qtreeview so I'll be able to update or insert data easily in my database ?

Note that I based my code on the `editabletreemodel` exemple from Qt's website : [editable tree model exemple](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_widgets_itemviews_editabletreemodel.html)

Here is the code that reproduces what I have on my ui :

**EDIT**
main.py :

```py
import sys

from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *




class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(573, 468)

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel()

        self.view = QTreeView()
        self.view.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.view.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)
        self.view.setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.view.setAnimated(False)
        self.view.setAllColumnsShowFocus(True)
        # self.view.setColumnHidden(1,True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.label)


        headers = ["value",'Type','Progress Bar','Test','Test','Test','Test']
        self.model = TreeModel(headers, self)

        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.expandAll()

        for column in range(self.model.columnCount()):
            self.view.resizeColumnToContents(column)



class TreeItem:
    def __init__(self, data: list, parent: 'TreeItem' = None):
        self.item_data = data
        self.parent_item = parent
        self.child_items = []

    def child(self, number: int) -> 'TreeItem':
        if number < 0 or number >= len(self.child_items):
            return None
        return self.child_items[number]

    def last_child(self):
        return self.child_items[-1] if self.child_items else None

    def child_count(self) -> int:
        return len(self.child_items)

    def child_number(self) -> int:
        if self.parent_item:
            return self.parent_item.child_items.index(self)
        return 0

    def column_count(self) -> int:
        return len(self.item_data)

    def data(self, column: int):
        if column < 0 or column >= len(self.item_data):
            return None
        return self.item_data[column]

    def insert_children(self, position: int, count: int, columns: int) -> bool:
        if position < 0 or position > len(self.child_items):
            return False

        for row in range(count):
            data = [None] * columns
            item = TreeItem(data.copy(), self)
            self.child_items.insert(position, item)

        return True


    def parent(self):
        return self.parent_item


    def set_data(self, column: int, value):
        if column < 0 or column >= len(self.item_data):
            return False

        self.item_data[column] = value
        return True

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        result = f"<treeitem.TreeItem at 0x{id(self):x}"
        for d in self.item_data:
            result += f' "{d}"' if d else " <None>"
        result += f", {len(self.child_items)} children>"
        return result




class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):

    def __init__(self, headers: list, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.root_data = headers
        self.root_item = TreeItem(self.root_data.copy())
        self.setup_model_data(self.root_item)

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = None) -> int:
        return self.root_item.column_count()

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = None):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if role != Qt.DisplayRole and role != Qt.EditRole:
            return None

        item: TreeItem = self.get_item(index)

        return item.data(index.column())

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.NoItemFlags

        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | QAbstractItemModel.flags(self, index)

    def get_item(self, index: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> TreeItem:
        if index.isValid():
            item: TreeItem = index.internalPointer()
            if item:
                return item

        return self.root_item

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation,
                   role: int = Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.root_item.data(section)

        return None

    def index(self, row: int, column: int, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> QModelIndex:
        if parent.isValid() and parent.column() != 0:
            return QModelIndex()

        parent_item: TreeItem = self.get_item(parent)
        if not parent_item:
            return QModelIndex()

        child_item: TreeItem = parent_item.child(row)
        if child_item:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, child_item)
        return QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> QModelIndex:
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()

        child_item: TreeItem = self.get_item(index)
        if child_item:
            parent_item: TreeItem = child_item.parent()
        else:
            parent_item = None

        if parent_item == self.root_item or not parent_item:
            return QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parent_item.child_number(), 0, parent_item)
    
    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> int:
        if parent.isValid() and parent.column() > 0:
            return 0

        parent_item: TreeItem = self.get_item(parent)
        if not parent_item:
            return 0
        return parent_item.child_count()

    def setData(self, index: QModelIndex, value, role: int) -> bool:
        if role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False

        item: TreeItem = self.get_item(index)
        result: bool = item.set_data(index.column(), value)

        if result:
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole])

        return result

    def setHeaderData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, value,
                      role: int = None) -> bool:
        if role != Qt.EditRole or orientation != Qt.Horizontal:
            return False

        result: bool = self.root_item.set_data(section, value)

        if result:
            self.headerDataChanged.emit(orientation, section, section)

        return result

    def setup_model_data(self, parent: TreeItem):
        parents = [parent]
        Data = [["Test 1",'diam',10,2,3,4,5,6],["Test 2",'len',55,2,3,4,5,6],["Test 3",'conc',64,2,3,4,5,6],["Test 4",'diam',9,2,3,4,5,6],["Test 5",'len',12,2,3,4,5,6]]
        for item in Data :
            parent : TreeItem = parents[0]
            col_count = self.root_item.column_count()
            parent.insert_children(parent.child_count(), 1, col_count)
            column_data = [item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3],item[4],item[5],item[6]]

            for column in range(len(column_data)):
                child = parent.last_child()
                child.set_data(column, column_data[column])



if __name__=="__main__" :
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: Your question is unclear. First of all, what do you mean by "I can not access the data when it's hidden"? The fact that the column is not visible is irrelevant, the model contains all the data. That said, what is the actual problem? If you want to know if there is an automatic way to update your database from your model, there is none: you're using a completely custom structure based on the database query, meaning that the only way to update the database is to go in the opposite way.

Comment: Even if I put the data in the model, when I use the data() function to get the primary key that has been saved in the second column (which is hidden by the way), it returns None as it doesn't exists (data(0) returns the name, and data(1) returns None). I found on Qt's website that data() requires a QModelIndex and a Role, so what should I put in the parentheses to return the primary key of the item ?

Comment: If the model *does* have two columns, then the problem is probably in the implementation of `data()`, but we cannot really know because your code is incomplete, so please provide a valid [mre]. Note that it seems that you're trying to "invert" columns by using negative indexes; while it's technically correct, it's also unnecessary and confusing: just invert the order of the fields in the `SELECT`. Also, recreating the column data is quite pointless: it's exactly the same as `projet` or `ensemble`, and you should use `enumerate()` to properly iterate through the list while getting the index.

Comment: I Edited the post so you can now have the detail of the data function by going on the Qt's website where you can get the exemple I am using. Also, can you be a little bit more clear on how and where to use the enumerate function. I tried to put it after the print function that returns me what's in the Qtreeview when I click on an item but it returns the memory place where the data is... Could you write the line of code you were thinking about with this function please ?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I specifically asked for a MRE: questions should always be self contained, and we cannot just assume you're using that code as it is: for what we know, you could have made a typo or altered the behavior without realizing it. Please take your time and provide what has been asked.

Comment: I made a MRE from my code. I copied all the code I am using to display the data from the database to the Qtreeview. You should be able to see a button on the top left and a Qtreeview in the middle. I also gave the details of what's in my database so you can implement it in yours if needed.

Comment: It's unclear to me too. How did you hide the ID column? How did you update records in the database? Also your code is not a [mre] because it's not minimal.

Comment: I created a folder from scratch with just the classes I am using to build the Qtreeview and to load my data in the Qtreeview. So I don't really see how I can make it smaller. Furthermore, it is normal that it is not working because you don't have access to the database I am using. I don't know if I should edit my post with a code block where it works from a list because it will lose a little bit of sense in my opinion as I am trying to update records in my database with the primarykey of my items... I hide the column with the `self.view.setColumnHidden(1,True)` in the `mainwindow.py` file.

Comment: I feel I am a detective. Are you asking how to access second column in your ```MainWindow.onItemClicked()```? Do like ```self.view.currentIndex().siblingAtColumn(1).data()```. A ```QModeIndex``` instance maps to a column, not a row.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I found an alternative solution in the mean time :
`clickeditem = str(self.ui.FolderTree.currentIndex().internalPointer())
clickeditem = clickeditem.split(",")`
I wanted to know why does my solution works ? It returns the repr method (or str method if you implemented one), but I don't really understand why.

Comment: You have to write like "To @relent95, ..." to notify a commenter like me. The ```QModelIndex.internalPointer()``` returns the custom object used when calling the ```QAbstractItemModel.createIndex()```. In your case, it's a ```TreeItem```. So, ```self.view.currentIndex().internalPointer().data(1)``` will be equivalent to the ```self.view.currentIndex().siblingAtColumn(1).data()```. Anyway, if you edit the question for the [mre] guide, I'll answer it.

Comment: @relent95 I tried to edit my question following the MRO guide by creating a new project, adding only the things that are mandatory to be able to launch the main.py.  It is a miinimal and reproductible code isn't it ?

Comment: No it's not. If you don't want to edit the question, what about answering your own question?

Comment: @relent95 you should be able to answer the post as I made a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you for the answer, it works great.